# How to convert swagger.json to static HTML using ruby

Tags: ruby, swagger

I want to convert a given [swagger.json](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore.json) to my own static HTML.
However, I dont want to parse the entire JSON as the swagger json can be huge with a lot of nesting. Is there a nice tool or library to convert the JSON to ruby objects so that I can call them to create my customized HTML

Answer (score 1):

There's a Swagger parser for Ruby:
https://github.com/swagger-rb/swagger-rb

and also this fork:
https://github.com/alexpjohnson/swagger-parser

I haven't used them myself so can't vouch for them.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [JSON module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) in the standard library.

```
require 'json'

hash = JSON.parse(File.read("file.json"))
puts hash
```

Comment: I was thinking if there is a way which involves not parsing the entire JSON and probably if there exists a librabry which can extract parts of it and create ruby objects